# Should I give up on pursuing a PhD in Europe if I performed poorly in my master?

Tags: phd, masters, application

I'm currently a master student in an Erasmus Mundus program. Unfortunately for me, I have been doing badly. My overall grade on the first 3 semesters is a C. So far only my master thesis remains but I don't think even an A will make me go from a C to a B. Is it worth trying to apply for PhD positions or should I just give up and go to the industry.

Edit: more than three years after posting this, I am now writing my doctoral thesis.

Comment: Why do you want to pursue a PhD? It's a serious question because, if you're doing badly in your Masters, that indicates you aren't suited to a PhD. Why do you want to do it anyway? Was there some mitigating factor that made you do badly at your Masters, but the factor is gone so you should do well in your PhD?

Comment: Find a trusted faculty member at your institution and pay them a visit to talk over your hopes and your options.

Comment: The level between my undergrad university and my first master university was very high. There were many things I didn't know and the courses where very hard because of that. So the first semester was a catastrophe. As a consecuence I started to get extremely anxious during exams and I started to do many stupid mistakes like writing negative sign instead of positives or forgetting to write some terms of a formula which ultimately costed me a lot. Whenever I had to do exams via oral presentation, my kind just went blank. My confidence is nearly non-existent.

Comment: I want to do PhD because I want to do research. To work in a particular topic and develop it. That's what appeals to me but it seems like my masters performance may bring my dream down.

Comment: @JoséLinares You realise that this is exactly what a PhD and research in general is often like? You're thrown into a hard, high level top you effectively know nothing about and you get an even less structured approach than in classes. Instead you are expected to achieve something on your own, even though you will sometime only produce failures for months at a time. To top this you will be expected to give a confident oral presentation about your work at some points in time even though you might not yet understand what you are doing. If this causes you to seize up, doing a PhD is a bad idea.

Comment: It's not that I want to discourage you, from trying if you really want, it is just a warning to keep in mind reality. Research can be a lot of fun, but sometimes it just can be quite an anxiety-producing slog for months at a time. I think everyone in academia has seen some PhD-student who wasn't ready and couldn't cope with this and who ultimately quit after having the worst time of their life for a few years.

Comment: @mlk In my experience, there is little correlation between exam performance and research performance.  One requires you to regurgitate tons of standardized information in arbitrarily short amounts of time; the other requires you to know where to find things with much less stringent (and arbitrary) time restraints.

Comment: Congratulations on your progress.

Answer (score 3):

Anecdotal answer: I did pretty horribly in my first higher-level, bachelors mathematics courses, partly for health reasons and partly because I had never been challenged like that before.  I also performed horribly the first year of graduate school (equivalent to first year of masters in Europe).  I had to learn (not re-learn, but learn for the first time) basic proof techniques in analysis.  Not only did I eventually get a PhD, but also subsequent postdocs, and I have a growing number of publications.  Some of us just start off a bit behind and have to work harder to catch up.

At the same time, academia isn't the only place to do research.  There are many research-like positions in industry.  If research is your goal, do research.  You don't need a PhD to do research (but it can help in some cases).